# Can I add div contents after defining a div child using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can I add div contents (`innerText` / `textContent`) after adding a div in the parent class using JavaScript. I know it's confusing and also I am not sure whether my demand is correct or not.

Can someone just help how to achieve below HTML results using JS.

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="mesg left">
            <div class="username">
                You
            </div>
      The main content goes here
            <span id="time">08:23am</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

I had tried to achieve this but I my case the content comes up... Like(see the output html from what I have did from JS)

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="description">
            The main content goes here
            <div class="name">
                James
            </div>
            <span id="time">08:23am</span>
     </div>
</div
```

Comment: Can you add what your markup looks like before the update, and the JS you're using to make the update (as a [mcve]) as your question is a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: Is it an issue with the order the contents are in? What is the exact problem?

Comment: @Andy thanks for your query,  the container was already created in HTML and is accessed by getElementbyid and all the rest of things that I have shown in the code was generated by the JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Node.insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to place the text before the timestamp.

Given your HTML this would work:

```js
const time = document.getElementById("time")
const content = document.createElement("p")
content.innerText = "The main content goes here"

document.getElemenstByClassName("mesg left")[0]
  .insertBefore(content, time)
```